# google static map image help

Tags: php, google-maps

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=280x280&sensor=false&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_map_spin%26chld%3D1%257C0%257Cfff%257C11%257C_%257CHere|Berkeley,CA
```

if we open the image above it works well.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=cabindeck,Startrack&zoom=14&size=280x280&sensor=false&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_map_spin%26chld%3D1%257C0%257Cfff%257C11%257C_%257CHere|cabindeck,Startrack
```

the question is how di i give an error echo if it fails ? any ideas ?
btw im useing php

like

```
    function get( $address ){
    echo '<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' . $address . '
    &zoom=14&size=280x280&sensor=false&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_map_spin%26chld%3D1%257C0%257Cfff%257C11%257C_%257CHere|' . $address . '" alt="" />';
}
```

Comment: or maybe there is a map Parameters that can we use to display none if its unknown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it without ajax, the following may work. But it depends on the response curl gets back from google.

```
function getMap($address){

    //Target Url
    $target = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={$address}&zoom=14&size=280x280&sensor=false&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_map_spin%26chld%3D1%257C0%257Cfff%257C11%257C_%257CHere|{$address}";

    //run curl
    $curl_instance = curl_init($target);
    curl_setopt($curl_instance, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($curl_instance);

    //if the img did not come back
    if(curl_errno($curl_instance))
        return '<p class="error">Map Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . '</p>';
    else
        return "<img src=\"{$target}\" alt=\"Map\" />";

    //kill curl
    curl_close($curl_instance);
}

echo getMap($address);
```

Comment: anyway     $check_size = curl_getinfo( $target, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD );
    
    if ( $check_size == 1350 ) { work :)